# SYSECHO SAS--what should be happening?

Tags: sas, output, enterprise-guide

So I have the following code, I'll keep it simple. But I want to know what should be happening in SAS and where I should be getting the message output at because I currently can't see them and I'm not sure if my program is too large for SAS to process.

I am running EG 7.1.

```
%macro membership(club=);
    proc sql;
      do some stuff;

    quit;
%mend;
%membership(club=8th);
sysecho "1st membership table finished.";
```

Comment: check this out and you need to see task status https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2009/05/26/tracking-progress-in-sas-programs-in-sas-enterprise-guide/

Comment: Not directly related but if you are worried about the amount of data being processed you can checkout this open source project for monitoring the size of your WORK directory:  https://github.com/Boemska/worktop